# glob operator with for loop is stuck

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to traverse all files in /home directory recursively. I want to do some linux command with each file . So, I am making use of for loop as below:

```
for i in /home/**/*
```

I have put below statements as start of script as well:

- shopt -s globstar
- shopt -s nullglob

But its getting stuck in for loop. It might be the problem with handling so many files. If I give some another directory(with less no of files) to for loop loop, then it traverse properly.

What else I can try.

Complete code:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob
echo "ggg"
for i in /home/**/*
do
    NAME=${i}
    echo "It's there." $NAME
    if [ -f "$i" ]; then
        echo "It's there." $NAME
        printf "\n\n"
    fi
done
```

Comment: @choroba, I repeated the same query in unixexchange as well for better reach/response.

Comment: Yes, but you forgot to link it for better reach/response :-)

Comment: @Ghansham please don't do that. Posting the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites is against the rules. We now have two places with the same question and of course the same answers. I have now closed your question on U&L so this one can stay open.

Comment: @Ghansham About cross-posting, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't getting stuck. It will just be very, very slow since it needs to build up the list of all files before entering the `for` loop. The standard alternative is to use `find`, but you need to be careful about what exactly you want to do. If you want it to behave *exactly* like your `for` loop, which means i) ignore hidden files (those whose name starts with `.`) and ii) follow symlinks, you can do this (assuming GNU `find` since you are on Linux):

```
find -L . -type f -not -name '.*' -printf '.\n' | wc -l
```

That will print a `.` for each file found, so `wc -l` will give you the number of files. The `-L` makes `find` dereference symlinks and the `-not -name '.*'` will exclude hidden files.

If you want to iterate over the output and do something to each file, you would need to use this:

```
find -L . -type f -not -name '.*' -print0 | 
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do 
        printf -- "FILE: %s\n" "$file"
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this approach may help:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob
echo "ggg"

for homedir in /home/*/
do
    for i in "$homedir"**
    do
        NAME=${i}
        echo "It's there." "$NAME"
        if [ -f "$i" ]; then
            echo "It's there." "$NAME"
            printf "\n\n"
        fi
    done
done
```

---

**Update**: Another approach in pure `bash` might be

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

walktree() {
    local file
    for file in *; do
        [[ -L $file ]] && continue
        if [[ -f $file ]]; then
            # Do something with the file "$PWD/$file"
            echo "$PWD/$file"
        elif [[ -d $file ]]; then
            cd "./$file" || exit
            walktree
            cd ..
        fi
    done
}

cd /home || exit
walktree
```

Comment: That will do exactly the same thing as the OP. The only difference is that it will take time in the inner loop instead of the outer. But it won't be faster and in fact could be slower since it needs to build multiple file lists.

Comment: @terdon Assume there are 1000 users' home directories in `/home` and 1000 files in each home directory. `/home/**` will expand to a 1000000-file list at once. But `"$homedir"**` will expand to a 1000-file list on each iteration in the inner loop. It will break the file list down into smaller chunks.

Comment: This would miss any regular file that happens to reside in `/home`.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin yes, I know. But that won't make it faster. There is nothing running in parallel here, so each list will be processed separately but whatever overhead there is in starting to build the list will be repeated. So this will either be just as slow, or if it is different, it will be slower.

Comment: @terdon it isn't intended to be faster anyway. The OP wrote `It might be the problem with handling so many files` and `What else I can try`. The code may (or may not) solve the problem of `handling so many files`.

Comment: There is no problem of so many files. Bash's `**` can handle as many files as you want. The only "problem" is that it takes a long time so the OP thought it isn't working. This solution is not really any different to the original, the OP will experience exactly the same issues.

Comment: @terdon Yes, `**` can handle as many files as you want. But when the expansion of `**`  exceeds the available memory the process will slow down vastly due to thrashing, or perhaps get killed. This proposed solution might use the memory more effectively.

Comment: @terdon How can `bash` handle this when it runs out of memory? Does it have such magical power?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229932/discussion-between-terdon-and-m-nejat-aydin).

Comment: [Looks like you were quite right and I was wrong](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/639354/22222). Bash will exit if it runs out of memory and does not use temp files to get around it as I had thought. So yes, this could indeed get around an out of memory error if that is the problem. It isn't, in this case, since there OP only says the loop hangs which just means it's building up the files, but it could very well be the case in other instances.

Comment: @terdon Well, we don't know yet whether this is an `out of memory` case or not. It's quite possible that the operating system decided to use the swap space (if any) and started to thrash the disk to satisfy request for memory allocation, which could end up with the bash process to be killed in the end. Even if it didn't, the performance of the process (and even the whole system) could be heavily affected. My suggestion may (or may not) be a remedy for this problem.